# Polymer 2.0: why do we need an anonymous function when imperatively adding listener

Tags: javascript, reference, polymer, addeventlistener, polymer-2.x

In the new docs for Polymer 2.0 (https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners), it gives the following example:

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.addEventListener('click', e => this._myClickListener(e));
}
```

to add an event listener imperatively. If you wanted to remove a listener, we would have to do the following (according to the docs):

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this._boundListener = this._myLocationListener.bind(this);
}

connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', this._boundListener);
}

disconnectedCallback() {
  super.disconnectedCallback();
  window.removeEventListener('hashchange', this._boundListener);
}
```

This make sense to me on the surface; we need to make sure the same reference to the function is passed for both remove and add event listener since that's the way it indexes different listeners.

However, why do we have to use .bind(this)? I understand it returns a new function that binds the function to whatever "this" is, so it's useful to make a new reference to a function that's saved so we can add and remove the same function reference.

But why can't we do that with the first example? Doesn't this._myClickListener(e) in the first segment of code also have a unique function reference that doesn't change that we can reference to add and remove a listener? Why do we need to wrap it in an anonymous function in the first place? I feel like that would solve the problem that was solved verbosely in the second segment of code, but it's clearly done this way for a reason.

Thanks for any help or suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would pass `this._myClickListener` as callback, then it wouldn't be called with the `this` value you want, since it is the DOM implementation that triggers the call to it, and it will not know about your `this`: `this` will just be the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode).

You could then say, OK, I will bind `this` to it with `this._myClickListener.bind(this)`, but now you don't have the reference to that function, which is created on the spot. When trying to call `removeEventListener` you cannot get an access to it with `this._myClickListener.bind(this)` as that just creates a new function again, which is not the one you used before.

So, there is no other way than to assign the bound function to a variable, and use that variable in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`: this is the only way to satisfy the two conditions at the same time:

- You have the reference to the function
- The function is bound to the correct `this`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the method of an object as a parameter to a function/method it is out of its natural context (`this` is not attached to the original object) which is why, to still use it as if it was a regular call to the method on that object, you use `bind` which explicitly binds the context and returns the function bound to that context.